# How can I open a link from one WebBrowser control in another WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I've created a simple webpage html scraper to retrieve news headline hyperlinks from a local online news site and display them scrolling across a full-screen-width x 150px WebBrowser control (HeadlineLinkBrowser).

Each time a headline link is selected, a new default web browser (in this case Chrome) window opens and the news story is displayed.

Can I access or modify the hyperlink click event, or is there any other approach I can use, in order to have the hyperlink navigate to *another WebBrowser control* (StoryTextBrowser) within the application rather than opening a new Chrome window?

I'm relatively new to C# development and a complete newb with WPF..

Comment: Why don´t you create a HTML page with a FRAMESET TAG, containing Two frames, one frame Containing a simple webpage html scraper, and the Other frame to be the Target. Then load the HTML containing this Frameset in the WebBrowser.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample WPF app which opens all navigation links (including the new window links) in another instance of WPF `WebBrowser`. It uses the underlying `WebBrowser` ActiveX control to get there and depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly. Generate SHDocVw.dll first: `tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll`, then add as a reference to the project. Note how `manualNavigation` is used to differentiate between user navigation and program navigation (via `webBrowser.Navigate`).

**C#**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WpfWebBrowser
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/19170109/1768303

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static object GetActiveXInstance(WebBrowser wb) {
            // get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
            // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
            // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
            // and add as a reference to the project

            return wb.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, wb, new object[] { }) as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                var axWbMainV1 = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)GetActiveXInstance(this.wbMaster);
                var axWbSlaveV1 = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)GetActiveXInstance(this.wbSlave);

                var manualNavigation = false;

                // Use WebBrowser_V1 events as BeforeNavigate2 doesn't work with WPF WebBrowser
                axWbMainV1.BeforeNavigate += (string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Cancel) =>
                {
                    if (!manualNavigation)
                        return;
                    Cancel = true;
                    axWbMainV1.Stop();
                    axWbSlaveV1.Navigate(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
                };

                axWbMainV1.FrameBeforeNavigate += (string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Cancel) =>
                {
                    if (!manualNavigation)
                        return;
                    Cancel = true;
                    axWbMainV1.Stop();
                    axWbSlaveV1.Navigate(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
                };

                axWbMainV1.NavigateComplete += (string URL) =>
                {
                    manualNavigation = true;
                };

                axWbMainV1.FrameNavigateComplete += (string URL) =>
                {
                    manualNavigation = true;
                };

                axWbMainV1.NewWindow += (string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed) =>
                {
                    if (!manualNavigation)
                        return;
                    Processed = true;
                    axWbMainV1.Stop();
                    axWbSlaveV1.Navigate(URL, Flags, String.Empty, PostData, Headers);
                };

                manualNavigation = false;
                axWbMainV1.Navigate("http://www.w3.org/");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="800" Height="600">
    <StackPanel>
        <WebBrowser Margin="4" Name="wbMaster" Height="300"/>
        <WebBrowser Margin="4" Name="wbSlave" Height="300"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```